# Update int column values mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to update an int column values where I want to set the value of the int column to `1` for the latest inserted record and increment it by `1` for all the preceding records until the record with Primary Id = 1 is reached. I've some 1400 records so what I want is that 1400 record should get 1 for that int column and the 1399 should get 2 and so on until all records are finished. How should the update query be written so that can be achieved. Thanks

Note this is going to be one time operation.

Comment: "...for the latest inserted record" -- There's no such a thing in a relational database. Rows do not have inherent ordering. What ordering criteria do you want?

Comment: I've a column to store the order. What I want is to set order to `1` for the latest inserted row and decrement by `1` for the rows preceding the latest record until all records are finshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()` for this. Assuming that you have a unique, ordering column called `id`, and that you want to update column `new_id`:

```
update mytable t
inner join (select id, row_number() over(order by id desc) new_id from mytable) x
    on t.id = x.id
set t.new_id = x.new_id
```

In earlier versions, one option is to emulate the window function with a user variable:

```
update mytable t
inner join (
    select t.id, @new_id := @new_id + 1 new_id
    from (select id from mytable order by id desc) t
    cross join (select @new_id := 0) x
) x on t.id = x.id
set t.new_id = x.new_id
```

Comment: I'm running MYSQL 8.0 and It worked like a charm. Thank you @GMB